# Intellij isn't analysing my code

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a scala project that I'm working on in Intellij. When I opened it up this morning, suddenly none of the code is being analysed properly. The main things I've noticed are that it says every variable is unused (even when it's used in the next line), it doesn't show an error if I try to use a variable that doesn't exist, and I don't get any errors if I try to use a class I haven't imported. TODOs also don't come up in blue.

Does anyone know if there is some sort of setting that somehow could have changed that would affect this? The problem only happens in this one project, all of my other projects are fine.

Edit: I have tried closing it and opening it again, invalidating the cache and restarting and restarting the entire computer.

Edit 2: I forgot to say, if I try to run a test it will come up with the correct compilation errors for things that shouldn't work, but it still doesn't show the error in the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why it happened, but I fixed it. I deleted the .idea folder and re-imported the project, and everything was analysed properly.